# Autocomplete issue in append html

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make autocomplete in appended field.
My codeigniter view file:

```
<div class="right_col" role="main"> 
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="x_panel">            
              <span class="section">Search Product's Info</span>
                <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Product Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input id="prosearch" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="prosearch" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                   </div> 
                </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
   $(function() { 
   // alert('hello');
    $( "#prosearch" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
      var t = $('#prosearch').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('sale/search') ?>",
        data: { term: request.term },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data ) {
           response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                  return {
                   label: item.data,
                   value: item.product_name,
                   id: item.id          
              }
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  })
});  
</script>
```

My Controller method:

```
public function search(){
  $q=$_POST["term"];
  #print_r($q); exit;
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '".strtoupper($q)."%';");        
  $data= $query->result_array(); 
  $json  = json_encode($data);
  echo $json;
}
```

My output is:
[image]

Well i am trying to my search result is under own input like any other autosuggestion. 
Any kind of help.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Anyway I'm not really sure what your actual issue is? Are your results what you expected? Are you trying to say there's an issue with the display format (e.g. missing CSS or something)? Your description in the last sentence is not very clear.

Comment: yes, my result is not display as i expected.

Comment: have you included the relevant CSS file, if any? Did it load properly?

Comment: yes, i'll check all files and its loaded properly.

Comment: that seems unlikely really, unless you've modified the CSS to be very basic. You can right-click on the results and inspect the elements in your browser tools to see if the expected CSS rules are being applied to them or not, and where the rule comes from. You can also see if some other CSS is over-riding those rules in any way.

Comment: P.S. You haven't said which autocomplete plugin this is, but if it's jQueryUI autocomplete then it should have a specific CSS theme file which must be included in the page, and must have been built from the jQueryUI site to include the autocomplete-related CSS.